# Strange jQuery AJAX problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, preloader

I'm using jQuery AJAX to grab some data from a PHP page and using a loading GIF image in the placeholder to let the user know the results are on the way.

```
$(".project").change(function(){
            $(".custName").html("<img src='/admin/images/ajax-loader.gif' />");
            $(".projectDesc").html("<img src='/admin/images/ajax-loader.gif' />");
            var project_num=$(this).val();
            var dataString = 'project='+ project_num;

                $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "customerfilter.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            $(".custName").html(data.message1);
                            $(".projectDesc").html(data.message2);
                        }
                    });


        });
```

When i click the trigger and open up Firebug console i can see the POST go and come back and the data is correct. However the loading gif never goes away and never gets replaced by the correct data - no idea why!?

This is a screenshot of Firebug and the RESPONSE window:

[image]

Relative PHP:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo json_encode(array(
                    "message1" => $row['cust_name'],
                    "message2" => $row['description'],
                ));
```

$result is a mysql_query

Comment: show us the data that comes back and possibly the php that generates it.

Comment: Check if the 'success' callback works. Put a console.log into for example. When the response is not valid json, the callback is not being called correctly.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to step through the "success" callback?

Comment: Your PHP return the `Content-Type: application/json` header ? If you do `console.log(data)` inside your success function, do you see something like this: `{ message1: 'asd', message2: 'qwe' }` ?

Comment: That response is not a valid json.

Comment: Add another callback to your ajax call:  `error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)` with alerts of the last two parameters.  Most likely there's a problem with the format of your JSON, or with your response headers, or some such; getting the reason that jquery isn't calling success will help you a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That response is not a valid json. Try this:

```
$output = Array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $output[] = Array(
                    "message1" => $row['cust_name'],
                    "message2" => $row['description'],
                );
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

EDIT: additionally, you have to change your 'success' javascript callback too:

```
success: function(data) {
  $(".custName, .projectDesc").empty();
  for(var x in data) {
     $(".custName").append(data[x].message1);
     $(".projectDesc").append(data[x].message2);
  }
}
```

Comment: The 'success' callback runs now?

Comment: apologies, since you added the jQuery...perfect! Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar problems when setting the type to be JSON. If the PHP doesn't return 100% correct JSON, then jQuery will not run the `success` function.

So try this:

1. Put a `console.log("success was called")` statement inside of the `success` method so that you can see when it's called.
2. Ensure that your PHP code is creating proper JSON by using the `json_encode` function.
3. Post any new information you have so we can continue to help you debug :-)